# `require`ing user-installed Ruby module

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've successfully installed my ruby gem to a subdirectory of `~` using the `--user-install` option to gem.  I can now see it under `~/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/`.

However, I'm unable to `require` it from my script:

```
./public_html/tt_web/index.cgi:2:in `require': no such file to load -- mbox (LoadError)
    from ./public_html/tt_web/index.cgi:2
```

I added `~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin` to my `PATH` variable per the information [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install) (and I've verified it actually worked with `echo $PATH`).

What else do I need to load gems from a custom path?

Here is the output of `gem env`, if it helps:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/elliott/.gem
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => ["/home/elliott/.gem", "/var/lib/gems/1.8"]
     - "install" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Did you install the `gem mbox`?

Comment: yes. "I've successfully installed my ruby gem..."

Comment: Not that. Did you run `gem install mbox` command? For more information see https://rubygems.org/gems/mbox

Comment: Yes, of course. I ran it with the `user-install` flag to install to my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea why this works, but adding `require 'rubygems'` to the top of my code fixed everything.  Perhaps someone else could still shine some light on *why*, but I'm just happy it's working now :)